# Mobile SDK: Product not connected on Android 11 (pixel 4a)

Tags: dji-sdk

Whatever the sdk version used, the onProductConnect is never called with the sample mobile app (and our custom mobile app).
I've noticed that the system connection popup (to allow access from the mobile to my inspire 1) is never showed as it could be with other mobile running on android 10.
My mobile is connected through USB wire on the remote control.

Is a known bug? How to fix this issue please?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the accessory filter. Should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <usb-accessory model="T600" manufacturer="DJI"/>
    <usb-accessory model="AG410" manufacturer="DJI"/>
    <usb-accessory model="com.dji.logiclink" manufacturer="DJI"/>
    <usb-accessory model="WM160" manufacturer="DJI"/>
</resources>
```

Clean and rebuild, uninstall and reinstall the app. (Must be asking for permissions at first startup)